# Programatically Converting Doc to Docx bug

Tags: c#, java, interop, docx, doc

I am trying to convert all the .doc documents in a server to a .docx format in order to modify them programatically using Java. I am not very adept at C#, but I was able to find this program and modify it for my needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;

namespace ConvertDOCtoDOCx
{
public class ObjectConstants
{
public static Object MissingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
public static Object True = true;
public static Object False = true;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "Z:\\PREE\\";

        foreach (string letters in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            foreach (string students in Directory.GetDirectories(letters))
            {
                foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(students, "*.doc"))
                {
                    Console.Write(file);
                    ConvertDocToDocx(file, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".docx");
                }
            }

        }

    }

    public static void ConvertDocToDocx(string docFilePath, string outputDocxFilePath)
    {
        var app = new Application();
        app.Visible = false;
        var doc = OpenDocument(app, docFilePath, false);
        SaveDocAsDocx(app, doc, outputDocxFilePath);
        app.Quit(ref ObjectConstants.False, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue);
    }

    public static void SaveDocAsDocx(Application app, Document doc, object outputFilePath)
    {
        object format = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument;

        try
        {

            doc.SaveAs(ref outputFilePath, ref format,
            ref ObjectConstants.False, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    public static Document OpenDocument(Application app, object filePath, bool visible)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = (Document)app.Documents.Open(ref filePath, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue,
            ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue, ref ObjectConstants.MissingValue);


            if (!visible)
            {
                doc.ActiveWindow.Visible = false;
            }

            return doc;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Every time I run it, the new docx files are not being created. I was able to narrow down the problem and I found the following line to be the culprit:

```
ConvertDocToDocx(file, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".docx");
```

When I leave the line as it is, nothing is created. But when I manually add it like the following example:

```
ConvertDocToDocx("Z:\\PREE\\1-ABC\\Alan Wernick\\new.doc", "Z:\\PREE\\1-ABC\\Alan Wernick\\new.docx");
```

It creates the file exactly where its supposed to be. Why is this happening?

Comment: Any reason you assigned `false` to `True`?

Comment: @recursive this is not entirely my code. I found it online and modified the main method to fit my server's needs.

Comment: @AlanW you may want to print the value of `file` and `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)`. see if it exactly the same as `"Z:\\PREE\\1-ABC\\Alan Wernick\\new.doc"` and `"Z:\\PREE\\1-ABC\\Alan Wernick\\new"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` only returns the name of the file, not the full path.

You end up passing the value `new.docx` as the second parameter to `ConvertDocToDocx`, not the full file path. It's probably writing it to disk *somewhere*, but who knows exactly where.

---

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get the full directory as well:

```
var baseFile =
   Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

ConvertDocToDocx(file, string.Concat(baseFile, ".docx"));
```